# Depend on one module which has profile for its transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have one project (say my_project) and it depends on module_A which has 2 profiles (profile_1, profile_2). and Each profile specify different versions of its dependency module_B(say version_1, version_2). Now my project can also depend on 2 different versions of module_B. So how can I build my_project using different versions of module_B ? Thanks

```
my_project
  - module_A
    - profile_1 (version_1 of module_B)
    - profile_2 (version_2 of module_B)
```

Comment: Simply wrong way. If you have a project which needs different versions either you should make separate projects of it m1 with dep 1 and m11 with dep 2 and may be you need to extract common code into a separate module or maybe even better change your project that it works with most recent? Why do you have this problem? Can you explain more in detail why you need different versions?

Comment: Actually module_A is external dependency project which has 2 profiles, I don't have control on that.